# Adding additional arguments in R function not defined inside

Tags: r

I have a function

```
test <- function (a,b,c) {
       #test
}
```

I have arguments a,b,c defined in the call. But i would like to have the option for additional arguments not defined in the function call, but if a user would to input test(1,2,3,d =4) it would still evaluate.

How could I do this in R?

Comment: Use `...` in function. `test <- function (a,b,c, ...) {}`

Comment: For more on `...`, see `help(dots)`.

Comment: So would I just use ... in the function call. And then add d somewhere inside the function?

Comment: Yes, to the extent that the additional `d` makes sense in the function context.

Comment: You can get the list of additional function arguments with `list(...)` inside the function.

Comment: You would need to unpack the dots with `list(...)` and check to see whether `d` exists, then handle it as needed in your function.

Comment: Are there any links I can read on this? With unpacking arguments and such? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To provide an example to the discussion in the comments regarding `...`, here is a function that draws a random variable from a given distribution then multiplies it by some number. Here, `a` is the number of random variables, `b` is the multiplier, and `c` is the specified distributions. Since some distributions have multiple parameters, you will need to use `...` to afford the flexibility of adding additional elements in the function:

```
funct <- function(a, b, c, ...){
  val <- c(a, ...)
  return(val*b)
}
```

If we try with the negative binomial (2-parameter distribution):

```
set.seed(123)
# Negative Binomial
funct(a = 10, b = 2, c = rnbinom, mu = 1, size = 0.5)
# [1] 2 0 4 0 0 2 0 0 2 2
```

If we try with the Poisson (a 1 parameter distribution):

```
# Poisson
funct(a = 10, b = 2, c = rpois, lambda = 1)
# [1] 2 2 0 6 0 0 6 2 0 2
```

Comment: How do people usually do documentation for dot( ... ) arguments?